# JSF/ primefaces validations not working inside datatable on Ajax event on first rendering

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The first time page is loaded the validation does not seem to work - I don't get error message but if I refresh the page or submit it, validations start working.

below is the code and it's linked to session managed bean.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{claimItem.claimItemList}" var="CdeClaimItem"
            id="dataTableClaims">
            <h:column>
                <h:inputText value="#{CdeClaimItem.feeScheduleCd}" id="fsc" 
                       style="text-align: center; width: 127px"
                        required="true" 
                        requiredMessage="Fee must be entered">

                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="fscMsg"></p:ajax>

                </h:inputText>              

                <h:message id="fscMsg" for="fsc"></h:message>

            </h:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a simalar problem and it was related to nested forms, which is not allowed.
Be sure your dataTable is wrapped by one `<h:form>`.

You may want to reivew this answer to rule out other issues:
[commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)

Since you are using `<p:ajax>`, I would also recommend using all Primefaces tags (`<p:column>`, `<p:dataTable>`, etc) . They might play nicer together.